# Moving a Ball in Random place with mouse click

Tags: python, button, pygame, mouse

The following program I have provided below is one I developed to have a ball move around a screen randomly on its own free will. The next thing I have been trying to make it do is to have it move to a random location if you click the ball with a mouse. I've tried if statements but can not get any to work?? Any ideas?? Would really appreciate the help!

```
   from pygame import * 
import random
init()
size = width, height = 800, 600
screen = display.set_mode(size)

#Setting up colour
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# setting up constants to help with the parts of the list
BALLX = 0
BALLY = 1
BALLSPEEDX = 2
BALLSPEEDY = 3

# function to set up a ball with random attributes
def initBall():
    ballx = random.randint(0, 800) # randomly setting the x position
    bally = random.randint(0, 600) # randomly setting the y position
    dirx = random.randint(-5,5)    # randomly setting the x speed
    diry = random.randint(-5,5)    # randomly setting the y speed
    data = [ballx, bally, dirx, diry]  # returning a list with all the data the ball needs
    return data # returning the list

def moveBall(data): # takes in the list of the ball
    data[BALLX] += data[BALLSPEEDX] # increases the position of the ball
    data[BALLY] += data[BALLSPEEDY]

    # checks to see if the ball is hitting the walls in the x direction
    if data[BALLX] > 800:
        data[BALLX] = 800
        data[BALLSPEEDX] *= -1
    elif data[BALLX] < 0:
        data[BALLX] = 0
        data[BALLSPEEDX] *= -1

    # checks to see if the ball is hitting the walls in the y direction
    if data[BALLY] < 0:
        data[BALLY] = 0
        data[BALLSPEEDY] *= -1
    elif data[BALLY] > 600:
        data[BALLY] = 600
        data[BALLSPEEDY] *= -1

    return data # returning the updated list

def drawScreen(data):   # sends a ball to be displayed
    draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, 800, 600))
    # drawing a ball at the x and y position
    draw.circle(screen, RED, (data[BALLX], data[BALLY]), 10)
    display.flip()


running = True      # variable that controls the main loop
myClock = time.Clock()  # for controlling the frames per second

ball = initBall()   # initializing the ball
# Game Loop
while running == True:  # do this loop as long as running is True
    # events all ready
    for evnt in event.get():             # checks all events that happen
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx, my = evnt.pos          
            button = evnt.button

    # calling the draw screen function and sending the ball information
    drawScreen(ball)
    # moving the ball function, notice ball = the returned value
    ball = moveBall(ball)

    myClock.tick(60)        # waits long enough to have 60 frames per second

quit()
```

Comment: Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135712/pygame-collision-detection-with-two-circles

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to do is get a rect around your ball.**

Ok, so basically what you need to do is , get the mouse coordinates and check if they collide with your ball image.
You can use the following code in your loop to check if mouse coordinates collides with the ball(rect).

```
 for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if ballrect.collidepoint(x, y):
                ballrect.center=(random.randint(5,1060),random.randint(5,700))

                continue
```

Comment: so would you replace the bottom portion of the code with this one??

Comment: To be precise your running loop.Change the coordinates of the random movement of the code ballrect for better results.